# Non-uniruled connected smooth fibers implies flat

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces, birational-geometry

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a surjective morphism of connected smooth projective varieties over an algebraically closed field.

Assume all fibers are connected smooth and none are uniruled. Is $f$ flat?

In particular if all fibers are abelian varieties is $f$ flat? Can the general fiber be e.g. a point and the special fiber be an elliptic curve?

Comment: All fibers are smooth, or the generic fiber is smooth?

Comment: @AmorFati all fibers are smooth

Comment: "Can the general fiber be e.g. a point and the special fiber be an elliptic curve?" 
 Welcome new contributor.  That certainly cannot happen.  Abyhankhar proved that for a birational morphism to a smooth target the irreducible components of fibers are point or ruled varieties.  That suggests an approach to your general question.  Consider the rational transformation from $Y$ to the Chow variety of $X$ determined by the fibers of $f$.  If the morphism is not flat, then the closure of the graph of this rational transformation has some uniruled fibers . . .